# What are the conditions that make PostgreSQL row-level locks access the disk

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) says:

> PostgreSQL doesn't remember any information about modified rows in memory, so there is no limit on the number of rows locked at one time. However, locking a row might cause a disk write, e.g., SELECT FOR UPDATE modifies selected rows to mark them locked, and so will result in disk writes.

Does any other of the row-level locking modes can also write to the disk?

What are the conditions that make each type of row-level lock access the disk?

Comment: I though there would be someone knowledgable that could answer this question, but perhaps I should search for an answer in another forum ...